# Update is not complete?

Tags: 12.04

I'm facing the following problem while I run update in my terminal. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one incompatible source available.

To check whether your system architecture is 32 or 64 bit, Enter the following in the terminal.

uname -i

If you are running a 32 bit system, the output will be:
i386

Thus, for a 32bit system, open your sources.list file with gedit:

gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

and completely remove any line that contains amd64 Packages.

Apparently, for a 64-bit system remove the line that contains the i386 packages.

After you have edited your sources.list, saved it, and closed gedit, enter these commands:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

1. Go to **System Tools**>**Administration**>**Software Updater**
2. Click on **Other Software** tab and remove tick from one `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages`

3.Now close the window.
4. Happy updating.